# Defining a set of relation fields for a generic view in Django

Tags: python, django, relationship, django-models

Well, i'm using a generic view to display my selected fields defining my method **fields**, it works, but what i'm trying to do it's as follows, in one of my custom fields i want to retrieve name value of 'Agentes' matching with his 'idagente' in my class 'Tareas',

```
class Tareas(models.Model):
    fechatarea = models.DateTimeField(null=True, db_column='fechaTarea', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    horainicio = models.DateTimeField(null=True, db_column='horaInicio', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    horafin = models.DateTimeField(null=True, db_column='horaFin', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    observaciones = models.TextField(blank=True)
    unidades = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    validar = models.IntegerField()
    idtipotarea = models.ForeignKey(Tipotarea, db_column='idtipotarea')
    idtarea = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='idTarea')
    idagente = models.ForeignKey(Agentes, db_column='idagente',blank=True, null=True)
    def __fields__(self,profile):        
        fields=[]
        fields.append( ('idagente'), _('Tipo de Agente')) )
        fields.append( ('fechatarea', _('Fecha de Tarea') ) )
        fields.append( ('horainicio', _('Inicio') ) )
        fields.append( ('horafin', _('Fin') ) )
        fields.append( ('unidades', _('Unidades') ) )    

        return fields
```

In my model class por Agentes i've defined a **unicode** method that's returning the name of my employee but always print his id, i'm forgetting something when i make my relationship to my field?

Comment: I respond myself, the problem was that i wasn't defining the related_name to my model i want to take his value, so finally i have this:

idagente = models.ForeignKey(Agentes, db_column='idagente',blank=True, null=True, related_name="Agentes")